# Active sentences with an immediate passive insertion

Tags: grammar, active-vs-passive

I am confused about the usage and the correctness of the passive structure here. My question is if the sentence sounds ok. If there is anything wrong with the sentence, please highlight that so that I don't repeat the mistake.

> It will also be one of my duties that I make sure that customers are getting satisfied with the financial advice being given to them.

Comment: It just does not feel natural. Can you post the active too.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using the passive voice in a subordinate clause of a sentence where the maun clause uses the active voice or vice versa

> She grabbed the man who was being chased by the police.

Perfectly acceptable.

With that said, you are correct to feel that your suggested sentence sounds odd. It is awkward, verbose, and stilted.

> Another of my duties will be to ensure that customers are satisfied by the financial advice given to them